# Pointer inside a structure not changing when passing by reference C

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

So, I'm pretty new to the C language and I've been passed a project by my professor to make a game in C. My problem is, I created a structure like so:

```
typedef struct vector
{
    int parts;
    int dir;
} Vector;

typedef struct snake
{
    Vector* parts;
    Vector dir;
} Snake;
```

I'm trying to initialize the `parts` pointer within this function:

```
void init_snake(struct snake *snake, int size, int x, int y)
{
    snake->parts = (Vector *)malloc(sizeof(Vector) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //sets the body parts one after the other in a line
        snake->parts[i].x = x - i * PIXEL_SIZE;
        snake->parts[i].y = y;
    }

    //sets the snake direction to the left
    snake->dir.x = 1;
    snake->dir.y = 0;
}
```

But by doing that the array `parts` inside the snake pointer is not initialized as expected. By checking its size with `sizeof(snake.parts) / sizeof(Vector)` it returns 0. Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: Note that C doesn't have pass by reference; you're passing a pointer by value.

Comment: If you work on 32bit system, pointer has 4 bytes, so `sizeof(snake.parts)/sizeof(Vector)` is `4/8` - integer division truncates to 0. Works as expected.

Comment: You need to store the size separately, there's no way to get it back from a pointer!

Comment: By the way, general advice: If you do size checks, prefer `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` – *array* (!), doesn't work for pointers, as here – that's safer for the case you change the type of the array. Some prefer `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`, but that's equivalent...

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It likely is working, you're just confused about `sizeof`.  This operator measures the size (in bytes) of a *type*.  If you ask for the size of a value, it uses the type of that expression instead.

**This is a compile-time evaluation and therefore is not dynamic.**

`sizeof(snake.parts)` is the same as `sizeof(Vector*)` which will be either 4 or 8 bytes depending on whether you are compiling to a 32-bit or 64-bit target.  Therefore, it's not useful to determine the size of an allocation.

Generally, given a pointer, you cannot tell how large the allocation is. Usually this is handled by storing some kind of useful length somewhere else.  For example, you could modify `struct snake` to include an element count for `parts`:

```
typedef struct snake
{
    Vector* parts;
    int parts_size;
    Vector dir;
} Snake;
```

And set this value accordingly:

```
snake->parts = (Vector *)malloc(sizeof(Vector) * size);
snake->parts_size = size;
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working, i got confused by the `sizeof` function. I thought it returned the size allocated to the variable and not the size of the variable type.

Comment: @HenriqueSabino You're welcome. This is quite a common point of confusion.

Comment: `sizeof` is evaluated during program execution for variable length arrays.

Comment: the key point of `sizeof x`is that it gives you the size of `x`, not the size of whatever x might be pointing to.  compile-time/run-time has nothing to do with it.